Assistance with External User Invitations and MFA in Microsoft Entra ID
We are developing a web application hosted in Azure and are currently working on user management. We would like to invite external users who are also registered in Microsoft Entra ID. However, some of our client's organizations have policies that prevent their accounts from being invited and added to other Azure tenants.
To address this, we considered creating new user accounts within our Entra ID tenant. However, this requires using a new email address, which means we cannot create a user with an existing email address from another tenant.
As a potential solution, we considered implementing multi-factor authentication (MFA), where a verification code is sent to their corporate email address. This way, if the user leaves their company, they would lose access to their corporate email and would no longer be able to log in to our application.
A few questions we are seeking guidance on:

Is there a way to invite external users even if their organization's policies prevent it?
Can we implement MFA with their corporate email address, even if this is not their primary user account email address?

Note that an admin adds all users and there is no self-user registration.


No. Assuming the remote organization is using an allow list, and you're not on it, you cannot invite those people by their organization's address. You can either contact that organization to get on their list, or invite users based on another email address.

No. You could certainly create users in your own tenant, but email is only able to be used for SSPR in this case.


